# How are these two user drops different?

Tags: mysql-5.5, users

Other than the obvious, what is the difference between:

```
drop user user_01@host01;
```

and

```
drop user 'user_01'@'host01';
```

In a sample test, they both achieved the same result. From [Account Names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/account-names.html) docs (5th bullet point), looks like they are not the same ... yet they appear to do the same thing ... ?

MySQL 5.5 on Centos 6.x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are identical.

The bullet point you mention states:

> The user name and host name parts, **if quoted, must be quoted
>   separately.** That is, write 'me'@'localhost', not 'me@localhost'; the
>   latter is interpreted as 'me@localhost'@'%'.

And that is what you did, you quoted them separately. In other words, all these are equivalent:

```
drop user    user_01@host01;

drop user   user_01 @ host01 ;

drop user  'user_01'@'host01';

drop user 'user_01' @ 'host01' ;
```

---

And if you wrote:

```
drop user 'user_01@host01';
```

... it would be interpreted as:

```
drop user 'user_01@host01' @ '%';
```

Comment: Thanks @Phil. So I'm reading (perhaps incorrectly) the second one as drop the user "user_01@host" logging into the db from host "%" ... which is different from "user_01" logging in from "host01" ... which would be two different commands. Sorry, I am still lost as to how they are identicial ... )-:

Comment: They are identical because the parts either side of the @ sign are quoted individually. `drop user 'user_01@host01';` has both parts either side of the @ sign between the same quotation marks. Maybe English isn't your native language - the documentation is very clear in this regard.